# H2 database inserting data exception after adding new column with ALTER TABLE

Tags: jdbc, h2

I am adding new column to my table like below code:

```
    String sql = "ALTER TABLE PROJE_ALAN ADD NEWCOLUMN VARCHAR(30)";
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
    ps.execute();
    conn.close();
    ps.close();
```

This is adding a new column to my table but when I want to add new data throws an exception:

```
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "net.sourceforge.hatbox.RTreeInternalException: Unable to select meta node"; SQL statement: INSERT INTO "PROJE_ALAN" ( "THE_GEOM","JJ","KK","NEWCOLUMN" ) VALUES ( ST_GeomFromText ('MULTIPOLYGON (((-244856.06897661195 4166022.019422841, 189248.78294214187 4442270.561552957, 778743.439809086 4301679.785647452, 662817.7123080553 4101892.893571207, 83189.0748029009 3707252.1190996123, -244856.06897661195 4166022.019422841)))',23036),'','','') [50000-172]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158)
at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:281)
at org.h2.schema.TriggerObject.fireRow(TriggerObject.java:215)
at org.h2.table.Table.fireRow(Table.java:904)
at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:895)
at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:128)
at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:86)
at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:79)
at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:235)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:180)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:155)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insert(JDBCDataStore.java:1447)
... 17 more

    Caused by: net.sourceforge.hatbox.RTreeInternalException: Unable to select meta node
at net.sourceforge.hatbox.Lock.<init>(Lock.java:88)
at net.sourceforge.hatbox.RTreeSessionDb.<init>(RTreeSessionDb.java:75)
at net.sourceforge.hatbox.jts.InsertTrigger.fire(InsertTrigger.java:43)
at org.h2.schema.TriggerObject.fireRow(TriggerObject.java:201)
... 28 more

    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "PROJE_ALAN_COPY_11_5_HATBOX" not found; SQL statement: select node_data, id from "PUBLIC"."PROJE_ALAN_COPY_11_5_HATBOX" where id = ? FOR UPDATE [42102-172]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
at org.h2.schema.Schema.getTableOrView(Schema.java:419)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4808)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1099)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1705)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1813)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1699)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1542)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1530)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:405)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:218)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:425)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:374)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1138)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:70)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:644)
at net.sourceforge.hatbox.Lock.<init>(Lock.java:72)
... 31 more
```

If I restart my application then I can add new data to new table. I think problem can be refreshing indexes without restarting application. Maybe It is related with Hat Box.

So what am I missing?

Comment: Table not found usually means you are using a different database. What is your database URL? Could you use an absolute path to the database file, such as `jdbc:h2:/data/test`. Ensure you are not using a relative path such as `jdbc:h2:test`.

Comment: I am using absolute path to my database file. If I restart my application after adding new column, there is no problem but without closing application it throws exception. Also renaming any column works without any problem

Comment: OK I see, so it's not the database URL. The table name `PROJE_ALAN_COPY_9_0_HATBOX` is strange, it looks like a temporary table name; altering a table will first create a temp table and then rename it, but the suffix `_HATBOX` is strange - do you know whether hatbox is using a special "table engine" (that is, not a regular H2 table)?

Comment: Hm, I see the suffix `_HATBOX` is added by the Hatbox tool. The table name `PROJE_ALAN_COPY_9_0` is a temporary name only, it should never be visible to the tool or the application. I guess this happens because the hatbox trigger sees this temporary table while the data is copied... Could you post the complete stack trace please (if there is more)?

Comment: Hm, I'm not quite sure, but I think the problem is the way Hatbox is creating triggers. There seems to be a trigger on a temporary table for some reason. I guess it's possible to fix this in Hatbox, but I don't know Hatbox myself so I can't help. Does it work if you re-open the database after adding the column? Is this a possible workaround for you?

Comment: After adding the column, re-open works for me. I wrote about this issue to Hatbox discussion board, maybe they can help me. By the way thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not Hatbox's fault. It's a bug in H2. H2 engine is recreates triggers after an ALTER TABLE statement, but calling trigger.init with TEMP TABLE NAME. Because of that, the trigger is being initialized with the wrong table name. After creating triggers, H2 renames the table to the original value.

My workaround for this bug is (it's buggy too, but working):

Changed net.sourceforge.hatbox.jts.Insert, Update, Delete trigger init methods to

```
public void init(Connection con, String schema, String trigger, String table,
        boolean before, int type) throws SQLException {

    this.schema = schema;
    this.table = table;

    if(this.table.contains("_COPY_")) {
        this.table = table.substring(0, table.indexOf("_COPY_"));
    }
}
```

You have to be while using this, if you have *COPY* on your table name, it will not work. You may change `_COPY_` to `*_COPY_?_?` like regex matching.